# How to resize the column based on content - React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

react table version - 6.8.0

As the react table does not use html elements related to a table in html like (thead, tbody. Td, th, tr ...) I can't use the css property (table-layout: auto)

i can't update this library

Comment: Are you install package from this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-v6

Comment: no, im working on legacy project